# Як перекласти українською латинське слово "VS." (бажано так само у скороченій формі)?

Tags: переклад, from-english, скорочення

Як перекласти українською слово "VS." (скорочена версія від латинського [*versus*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C#vs), *«проти»*) бажано так само у скороченій формі? Тобто в ангмові надзвичайно поширена форма вжитку:

- Trump VS. Biden (Трамп супроти Байдена)
- Democrats VS. Republicans (Демократи проти Республіканців)

Я бачив деякі варіанти на Словотворі https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/vs , але на жоден варіант там не було надано АД джерела (словника, стильового підручника тощо), тож хотілося б почути що про це кажуть українські мовознавці.

Ще раз наголошується що важливим є надання україномовного **відповідника-скорочення**, тотбо насамперед цікавить скорочення схоже на VS. а не повнокровне слово як от Versus

Comment: А чим не підходять «проти» й «супроти»? Чи питання в тому, яке з них краще?

Comment: Питання в тому чи є усталений відповідник-скорочення у «проти» й «супроти» (чи іншого відповідника versus), наприклад «пр.» й «спр.» й бажано щоб цей відповідник-скорочення був не 100% словотвір, а скорочення яке або 1) зустрічається в українському сучукрліті чи 2) мовознавчих працях 3) словниках тощо

Comment: А, я зрозумів, мова саме про скорочення. Перепрошую, неуважно прочитав :(.

Comment: Від супроти можна отримати _с/п_.

Comment: Мені здається, що відповідного скорочення немає.

Comment: В сучасному вжитку, окрім «проти, супроти», часто можна зустріти позначку тире «—», рідше «і». Наприклад "Бій Усик — Чисора» або «Бій Усика і Чисори».

Comment: Тоді це нелогічний вжиток, який може дуже легко заплутати слухача. Якщо просто використовувати дефіс чи сполучник і/та/й, то як слухач може зрозуміти що ці дві речі є протилежностями?

Comment: Потрібно виправити заголовок, оскільки він містить слово "бажано", а в самому тексті вимагається скорочена форма. Відповідь на питання - "проти, скороченого відповідника немає".

Answer (score 2):

У нас узагалі нема скорочення-відповідника для VS. Це їхнє слово-реалія. Не все можна перенести в українську мову чи з неї в англійську. У кожної мови своя природа і реалії, свої лакуни.

Comment: Що таке "лакуни"?

Comment: @sashaeve [Lakuna](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Лакуна_(мовознавство))